# Swift: Store Type of implementation of Protocol in static var of protocol extension

Tags: ios, swift, macos, protocols, extension-methods

Okay so I have this protocol `MenuEntry` which I want to use to populate a TableView:

```
protocol MenuEntry {
    static var title: String { get }
    static func entrySelected(_ menuController: MenuController)
}
```

I want to implement this protocol in various places and let the item itself decide what to do. It might be a UIViewController which implements the protocol or a simple struct, which then calls a function on the menu itself:

```
struct SomeEntry: MenuEntry {
    static var title: String { return "Some Entry" }
    static func entrySelected(_ menuController: MenuController) {
        menuController.doSomething()
    }
}
```

Now I want to build the MenuControllers datasource but without actually instantiating the entries because especially my view controllers are not necessarily available when the MenuControllers datasource is populated. Thats why I use static var/func in MenuEntry. Currently, I can simply do this to populate the datasource:

```
let dataSource: [MenuEntry.Type] = [SomeEntry.self]
```

And it seems to work pretty well. I can get the entries and call the corresponding functions:

```
dataSource.first?.title   //Gives me "Some Entry"
```

Now comes the tricky part. I thought I could be really clever and create a protocol extension where I reference all the types in which I implement the protocol like so:

```
extension MenuEntry {
    static var someEntry: MenuEntry.Type { return SomeEntry.self }
    //...
}
```

And then later use them via `MenuEntry.someEntry`. However, accessing someEntry on MenuEntry gives me an error:

```
error: static member 'someEntry' cannot be used on protocol metatype 'MenuEntry.Protocol'
```

**So my question is**: what am I missing? Am I just trying to misuse the language in a way which is not intended or am I just doing something wrong?

**SOLUTION**

From the accepted answer below, heres how I now do things. First, we need the mentioned struct (no need for a class I guess):

```
struct MenuEntries {}
```

Then, where ever I implement the MenuEntry protocol, I also extend this struct and add the entry like so:

```
struct SomeEntry: MenuEntry {
    static var title: String { return "Some Entry" }
    static func entrySelected(_ menuController: MenuController) {
        menuController.doSomething()
    }
}

extension MenuEntries {
    static var someEntry: MenuEntry.Type { return SomeEntry.self }
}
```

The last thing is to create my datasource like so:

```
let dataSource: [MenuEntry.Type] = [MenuEntries.someEntry, ...]
```

Okay, now I have a list of all menu entries in one place. The downside is I have to remember to extend MenuEntries every time. Except there is some magical way to extend a struct on a conditional base I'm not aware of. But I guess thats just over the top and simply not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [*The Swift Book*](https://itun.es/au/jEUH0.l)

> A *protocol* defines a blueprint of methods, properties, and other requirements that suit a particular task or piece of functionality. The protocol can then be *adopted* by a class, structure, or enumeration to provide an actual implementation of those requirements.”

Your extension is attempting to implement functionality directly in the protocol, but this is not allowed; Only a class, structure or enumeration adopting the protocol can provide functionality.

You could define a class that returns your menu classes:

```
class MenuFactory {
    static var someEntry: MenuEntry.type { return SomeEntry.self }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That explains it well! I however went with a struct instead of a class (see the solution in my answer)